# What is the data format/structure Google Cloud Datastore use? Can I export data stored there to others provider?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I need a database for my online game and Google Cloud Datastore seem suitable. I just wonder if the data format there are proprietary and I'll be tied to their platform? The doc don't seem to mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is the open-source LevelDB logs format:

Format - https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/doc/log_format.md

Answer (score 0):

You can use the deferred library and the [documentation of the library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) provided a Mapper class that allows you to iterate the whole datastore. By doing so, you can export the datastore to whatever format you like and import it to other platform. It is the most flexible way I can think of.

Another way is that you backup the datastore by following the instruction in [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/managing-datastore). The backups are stored in google cloud storage. Maybe you can unzip and decode the data. but I don't know how the data are encoded. Maybe it is in ProtoBuf. Maybe You can import the backup to BigQuery and perform an export to some formats you can process.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no official documentation on the format, I did some digging and [wrote down the structure of the exports](https://github.com/remko/dsbackups/blob/master/doc/DatastoreExportFormat.md) as I was able to extract it.